UserInputService isn't detecting inputs
For some reason, my code doesn't work in any way. Does someone has an answer why UserInputService doesn't work for me?
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local debounce = false

UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, typing)
    print("input")
    if typing then return end
    
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        
        print(player, " pressed lmb")
        
    end
    
end)

I already tried multiple variants of my code, none of which work. For some reason, sometimes, key thingy works, and I can do something by pressing E or Q if I bind it using script.
I also tried changing devices, and currently writing this from my Laptop (I mainly do everything on PC.)

The answer was actually, that WaitForChild is better to be used in an if, for example:
if not character then
character = player:WaitForChild("Character")
